# Is there an alternative to using Frames to combine multiple aspx files into a single page?

Tags: asp.net, html, frameset

I am rewriting a site that contains around 10 separate frames which each display a bunch of separate aspx files.

Is there a modern-day equivalent to using Frames for combining multiple aspx files, without needing to rewrite all the individual aspx files that make up the frame's contents?

Answer (score 1):

How about turning the existing aspx pages into (user) controls? This would allow you to either dynamically add them (any/all, one or any number) to a single page or just statically (all ten) do so in markup.

You retain whatever rationale you had for creating 10 different pages while really wanting to display them together in some form/number yet maintain separation (in other/older platforms, this would be similar to `include` files)

[Converting aspx to ascx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728784%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) isn't too much work.

Depending on what you need next, you may need to do more work, likely using client side techniques (AJAX) if you want each of the controls functions not have to refresh the entire page (like in a frameset).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into doing this and let you know how it goes. Do you know if I can use a different language in the controls? Such as having the controls use VB.Net while the main site would use C#?

Comment: @Rachel - I've mixed and matched vb and c# aspx, as well as newer razor vbhtml and cshtml in a `Web Site` (not `Web Application`) without issues. On this one though, unsure - I've never tried. (updated): I think you'll run into issues because you'll be mixing languages in a (containing) Page. If you do try, I'd be interested in the result myself :)

Answer (score 0):

An ASP.NET master page may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't want to re-write the contents of all the content pages if possible, and I think I'll have to do that if I use a ASP.Net master page. There's a *lot* of content pages...

Comment: A Master page is probally the best answer other solutions would require more work and probally other HttpHandlers or an alternate PageHandlerFactory but thats a LOT more work.

Comment: @SaintGerbil How would that work? My initial page has about 10 different frames containing separate aspx files, and I would need to display them all at once. I thought master/content pages were for displaying a single page with a standard layout.