# Combining multiple asp.net pages into a single page

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-webpages

Is it possible to combine or bring in content on different aspx files under a single aspx page? However, I would like to achieve it without converting the aspx into ascx, thus no User Controls.

**NOTE:** I am open to using client-side scripting such as Javascript or Jquery. And no, this is not a duplicate [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512532/is-there-an-alternative-to-using-frames-to-combine-multiple-aspx-files-into-a-si).

**EDIT:** Even though this seems like a bad design idea, this is the functionality I want. All the pages should become the content of a single page, overlooking all individual CSS and Javascripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you can not do that, and if you have reached a point that you need to do it, then you have a bad design on your pages. Why? Because a full page contains not only content but also css, javascript, title, headers etc, that are unique and you can not mix with some other page with out issues like javascript and css conflicts. For eg. *What is the final title of the page?* and other such.

The alternative that you have is:

- the use of [`iframe`'s](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)
- the use of code behind to render a page dynamically and add it on a place holder.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an HTML [frameset](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html) to divide the page into separate frames, each one could have an ASPX page as its source.

Comment: The <frame> tag is not supported in HTML5.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Quite right, but the rendering of frames is being [defined](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/rendering.html#frames-and-framesets) for HTML5, so I would expect it to work in all contemporary browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it other than those suggested by Aristos and michielvoo is to use the JQuery .load() method. Make different content holders for the pages to displayed and set the HTML content of those pages to the content holders using JQuery selector.

Acc. to the JQuery Documentation

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server.When a
>   successful response is detected .load() sets the HTML contents of the
>   matched element to the returned data.

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

Comment: .load method will load all the html including asp.net hidden field. which contain the values of view state. And your page may currupt as there will be multiple hidden fields with the name _hidded

Comment: Agreed! It even leads to Css conflicts which don't occur while using frames, but nevertheless, this too is one way to achieve the objective(not perfect, but a way).

Comment: One way to get rid of this conflict is put your css and script on main page. Crete a container like div and load that div only. As follows $('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append the pages to each other, I do this for nationwide craigslist searches.

I append all results to a single page, then I view that page in a browser

You use a listbox, browser control, and then append the text to a single file